# Momentum operator in momentum representation in polar coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum

I would like to write Schrödinger equation in polar coordinates in momentum representation (because I have a potential depending only on distance) . Would momentum operator be still just a mupltiplication like in 1D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write the Schrödinger equation in $\lbrace|\mathbf{p}\rangle\rbrace$ representation you must project:

$$
i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=H|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

onto $|\mathbf{p}\rangle$.

Considering that for a particle in a scalar potential $V(\mathbf{r})$ (where $\mathbf{r}$ might be $(x,y,z),(r,\varphi,z)$ ...) the Hamiltonian operator is given by $H=\frac{1}{2m}\mathbf{P}^2+V(\mathbf{R})$ ($\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ are the momentum and position operators), we have:

$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\langle\mathbf{p}|\psi(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{2m}\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{P}^2|\psi(t)\rangle+\langle\mathbf{p}|V(\mathbf{R})|\psi(t)\rangle 
$$

At this point you have to consider that $\langle\mathbf{p}|\psi(t)\rangle=\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p},t)$ and also the answer to your question:

> Would momentum operator be still just a mupltiplication like in 1D?

Indeed, the rule of actuation of $\mathbf{P}$ operator in momentum representation is always a multiplication by the eigenvalue $\mathbf{p}$. The schrodinger equation then becomes:

$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p},t)=\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p},t)+\langle\mathbf{p}|V(\mathbf{R})|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

In order to calculate the last quantity we must insert the closure relation of the momentum representation:

$$
\langle\mathbf{p}|V(\mathbf{R})|\psi(t)\rangle=\int{d^3}p'\langle\mathbf{p}|V(\mathbf{R})|\mathbf{p}'\rangle\langle\mathbf{p}'|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

and keep in mind that for any function $F(\mathbf{r})$, the matrix element of $F(\mathbf{R})$ operator in momentum representation is given by:

$$
\langle\mathbf{p}|F(\mathbf{R})|\mathbf{p}'\rangle=(2\pi\hbar)^{-3/2}
\overline{F}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}')
$$

The schrödinger equation in momentum representation can finally be written as:

$$\boxed{
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p},t)=\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p},t)+(2\pi\hbar)^{-3/2}\int{d^3}p'\overline{V}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}')\overline{\psi}(\mathbf{p}',t)}
$$

---

$\overline{V}(\mathbf{p})$ is of course the Fourier transform of $V(\mathbf{r})$. In the case of the potential that only depends on $r$, $\overline{V}$ depends only on $p$ and could be written as:

$$
\overline{V}(p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\frac{2}{p}\int_{0}^{\infty}rdr\sin{\frac{pr}{\hbar}}V(r)
$$